# what does function def inside do blocks accomplish?

Tags: ruby, module, block, mixins

I'm fairly new to Ruby but I came across this weird gist where a function def code is written inside a do-block code. What is the purpose of this:

```
 module Hi
   def self.included(base)
     base.class_eval do
       def hello; puts 'Hello' end
     end
    end
 end
```

I'm sure I should first get my Mixin concepts straight before moving ahead (and I'm in the process of diving deeper into mixin's and whatnot) but the way def :hello is used inside the do-block is confusing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this particular bit of code does is a define a method (`hello`) in any class that `include`s this module. Given this, the following two bits of code are (roughly) equivalent:

```
class Foo
  include Hi
end

# ...is equivalent to...

class Foo
  def hello
    puts 'Hello'
  end
end
```

You'll find the documentation for [`Module#class_eval`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/class_eval) and [`Module.included`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/included) informative.

Comment: one more question, what happens when some other module includes "Hi" instead of a class and finally a class includes this new module?

Comment: I tried various things in irb, the Foo class objects don't get the hello method at all. Is there a trick to irb?

Comment: It works for me simply pasting your code and then my (first bit of) code into irb. Calling `f = Foo.new; f.hello` prints "Hello." As to your one-more-question, the behavior is the same, except that `self.included` is executed on the other module upon inclusion and not on the class.